# Makefile: comma split variable as multiple arguments

Tags: makefile

Consider following makefile example:

```
a=1,2,3
b=$1 $2 $3
$(info $(call b,$(a)))
```

Run this will give me `1,2,3` as output of `info` function. How can I let Makefile replace `a` and consider it as three arguments to `call`, then output `1 2 3`?

The only solution I can think of

```
comma=,
$(info $(call b,$(word 1,$(subst $(comma), ,$(a))),$(word 2,$(subst $(comma), ,$(a))),$(word 3,$(subst $(comma), ,$(a)))))
```

But it's painful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(eval $$(info $$(call b,$(a))))` works.

But you can't `eval` just the function call, so I've put `info` inside too. Perhaps you could do `$(eval foo := $$(call b,$(a)))` and then read the variable.